# How to fix erratic column spacing in bootstrap accordion card header?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, accordion

I have a bootstrap 4 accordion. Each card header is a row that contains 3 columns in it. My problems is that the spacing increases between the first and second columns when the text in the second column increases in length. This is especially noticeable on card 2B that has the text "FORMS COMPLETED" in the second column. How do I make the spacing consistent and even?

```
<!-- ###### Accordion ###### -->
            <div class="accordion" id="activityAccordion">
                <!-- Card 1 -->
                <div class="card py-0 m-1">
                    <div class="card-header p-1" id="heading1">
                        <button class="btn collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">
                            <div class="row p-0 m-0 text-left">
                                <div class="col-3 pl-0 pr-1 py-0 m-0 ">02/04/2019</div>
                                <div class="col-3 col-3 pl-0 pr-1 py-0 m-0" style="color:#1aa2c1">Phone Call</div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 pl-0 pr-1 py-0 m-0" style="text-transform:none">Followed up on smart goals</div>
                            </div>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading1" data-parent="#activityAccordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- / end  Card -->
                <!-- Card 2 -->
                <div class="card py-0 m-1">
                    <div class="card-header p-1" id="heading2">
                        <button class="btn collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">
                            <div class="row p-0 m-0 text-left">
                                <div class="col-3 pl-0 pr-1 py-0 m-0">01/25/2019</div>
                                <div class="col-3 col-3 pl-0 pr-1 py-0 m-0" style="color:#01c16d">Interview</div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 pl-0 pr-1 py-0 m-0" style="text-transform:none">Took PCL-5, GAD-7, and PIL</div>
                            </div>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse2" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading2" data-parent="#activityAccordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- / end  Card -->
                <!-- Card 2B -->
                <div class="card py-0 m-1">
                    <div class="card-header p-1" id="heading2B">
                        <button class="btn collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse2B" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2B">
                            <div class="row p-0 m-0 text-left">
                                <div class="col-3 pl-0 pr-1 py-0 m-0">01/12/2019</div>
                                <div class="col-3 col-3 pl-0 pr-1 py-0 m-0" style="color:#bea623">Forms Complete</div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 pl-0 pr-1 py-0 m-0" style="text-transform:none">Parents signed consent to treat, intake complete</div>
                            </div>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse2B" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading2B" data-parent="#activityAccordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- / end  Card -->
                <!-- Card 3 -->
                <div class="card py-0 m-1">
                    <div class="card-header p-1" id="heading3">
                        <button class="btn collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse3">
                            <div class="row p-0 m-0 text-left">
                                <div class="col-3 pl-0 pr-1 py-0 m-0">01/10/2019</div>
                                <div class="col-3 col-3 pl-0 pr-1 py-0 m-0" style="color:#a90092">Counseling</div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 pl-0 pr-1 py-0 m-0" style="text-transform:none">First visit, suspected depression</div>
                            </div>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse3" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading3" data-parent="#activityAccordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- / end  Card -->
                <!-- Card 4 -->
                <div class="card py-0 m-1">
                    <div class="card-header p-1" id="heading4">
                        <button class="btn collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse4" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse4">
                            <div class="row p-0 m-0 text-left">
                                <div class="col-3 pl-0 pr-1 py-0 m-0 ">02/04/2019</div>
                                <div class="col-3 col-3 pl-0 pr-1 py-0 m-0" style="color:#1aa2c1">Phone Call</div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 pl-0 pr-1 py-0 m-0" style="text-transform:none">Followed up on smart goals</div>
                            </div>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse4" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading4" data-parent="#activityAccordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- / end  Card -->
                <!-- Card 5 -->
A
                <!-- / end  Card -->
                <!-- Card 6 -->
                <div class="card py-0 m-1">
                    <div class="card-header p-1" id="heading6">
                        <button class="btn collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse6" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse6">
                            <div class="row p-0 m-0 text-left">
                                <div class="col-3 pl-0 pr-1 py-0 m-0 ">01/10/2019</div>
                                <div class="col-3 col-3 pl-0 pr-1 py-0 m-0" style="color:#a90092">Counseling </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 pl-0 pr-1 py-0 m-0" style="text-transform:none">First visit, suspected depression</div>
                            </div>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse6" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading6" data-parent="#activityAccordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- / end  Card -->
            </div>
<!-- / end  Accordion -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spacing is increasing because you have `<div class='row'>` inside button, and that button is adjusting its width according to content inside it hence that button that has more text gives its width to child row and columns and `<div class='col-3'>` doesn't have same width as div with same class from some other card that has different amount of text inside button.You can try putting fixed width on button with css like this

```
.btn{
    width:700px !important;
}
```

Comment: Alex helped me understand that the formatting structure for the button class was interfering with the columns. To keep everything responsive, I did not use a fixed width. I removed the button style from the accordion and changed it to a link style. See my code example on a separate answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

@Alex helped me understand that the formatting structure for the button class was interfering with the columns. To keep everything responsive, I did not use a fixed width. I removed the button style from the accordion and changed it to a link style.

```html
 <!-- ###### Accordion ###### -->
            <div class="accordion" id="activityAccordion">
                <!-- Card 1 -->
                <div class="card py-0 m-1">
                    <div class="card-header p-1" id="heading1">
                        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">
                            <div class="row p-0 m-1 text-left">
                                <div class="col-2 p-0 m-0">02/04/2019</div>
                                <div class="col-3 p-0 m-0 text-uppercase" style="color:#1aa2c1">Phone Call</div>
                                <div class="col-md-7 p-0 m-0">Followed up on smart goals</div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading1" data-parent="#activityAccordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- / end  Card -->
                <!-- Card 2 -->
                <div class="card py-0 m-1">
                    <div class="card-header p-1" id="heading2">
                        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">
                            <div class="row p-0 m-1 text-left">
                                <div class="col-2 p-0 m-0">01/25/2019</div>
                                <div class="col-3 p-0 m-0 text-uppercase" style="color:#01c16d">Interview</div>
                                <div class="col-md-7 p-0 m-0">Took PCL-5, GAD-7, and PIL</div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse2" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading2" data-parent="#activityAccordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- / end  Card -->
                <!-- Card 2B -->
                <div class="card py-0 m-1">
                    <div class="card-header p-1" id="heading2B">
                        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse2B" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2B">
                            <div class="row p-0 m-1 text-left">
                                <div class="col-2 p-0 m-0">01/12/2019</div>
                                <div class="col-3 p-0 m-0 text-uppercase" style="color:#bea623">Forms Complete</div>
                                <div class="col-md-7 p-0 m-0">Parents signed consent to treat, intake complete</div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse2B" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading2B" data-parent="#activityAccordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- / end  Card -->
                <!-- Card 3 -->
                <div class="card py-0 m-1">
                    <div class="card-header p-1" id="heading3">
                        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse3">
                            <div class="row p-0 m-1 text-left">
                                <div class="col-2 p-0 m-0">01/10/2019</div>
                                <div class="col-3 p-0 m-0 text-uppercase" style="color:#a90092">Counseling</div>
                                <div class="col-md-7 p-0 m-0">First visit, suspected depression</div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse3" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading3" data-parent="#activityAccordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- / end  Card -->
                <!-- Card 4 -->
                <div class="card py-0 m-1">
                    <div class="card-header p-1" id="heading4">
                        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse4" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse4">
                            <div class="row p-0 m-1 text-left">
                                <div class="col-2 p-0 m-0">02/04/2019</div>
                                <div class="col-3 p-0 m-0 text-uppercase" style="color:#1aa2c1">Phone Call</div>
                                <div class="col-md-7 p-0 m-0">Followed up on smart goals</div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse4" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading4" data-parent="#activityAccordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- / end  Card -->
                <!-- Card 5 -->
                <!-- / end  Card -->
                <!-- Card 6 -->
                <div class="card py-0 m-1">
                    <div class="card-header p-1" id="heading6">
                        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse6" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse6">
                            <div class="row p-0 m-1 text-left">
                                <div class="col-2 p-0 m-0 ">01/10/2019</div>
                                <div class="col-3 p-0 m-0 text-uppercase" style="color:#a90092">Counseling</div>
                                <div class="col-md-7 p-0 m-0">First visit, suspected depression</div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse6" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading6" data-parent="#activityAccordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- / end  Card -->
            </div>
<!-- / end  Accordion -->
```